# DataGridItem.FindControl doesnt find the control? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

```
Label lbl = dgi.FindControl("LBL_MyLabel") as Label;
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes lbl is null after FindControl was called. I am wondering how this could happen. It should either be there or not? Any ideas?

The label is defined like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="LBL_MyLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

What's the broader context of the code around the call to `FindControl`?  This error is commonly experienced when iterating through the rows in the grid (such as in the `RowDataBound` event) without conditionally checking what the row type is:

```
if (e.row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  // your code
}
```

Wrapping it in that conditional will skip header/footer rows, which probably don't have your label control in them.

Comment: Its inside a TemplateColumn in my grid and its called in the ItemDataBound method of the grid. There is no special if(something) around it.

Comment: @grady: `ItemDataBound`?  Sounds like a classic `DataGrid`.  It also sounds like it's the same issue, just a different syntax.  For that you'd probably want a conditional like: `if((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))`

Comment: @grady: Not sure.  Is there anything different in an alternating item template?  When you debug, what controls are found within the item?  Conversely, if you set the conditional to only handle `ItemType`s of `ListItemType.Item` then does it catch all your rows?

Comment: How do I know the controls in an item?

Comment: @grady: I don't have anything handy to test this, but `e` should be of type `DataGridItem` which should have a `Controls` property.  That would be the best place to start.  I imagine the control hierarchy would be available in there, but I'm not 100% certain.  It might get cloudy depending on how dynamic the whole thing is and at what point things are bound/created.